# How can I prevent `C-s` from invoking I-search while using Smex?

Tags: key-bindings, ido, smex

While using `M-x` ; by default `C-s` was binding to next line so I used to keep pressing `C-s` to toggle around. When I start using `smex`, `C-s` is now it is bound to `I-search` in some cases as follows:

`M-x` than type `package` and press TAB two times and press `C-s` two times and `I-search:  [No previous search string]` message will show up.

Is it possible disable `I-search` and `I-search backward:` during usage of `smex`, where `C-s` and `C-r` would be bound to `nil`.

my setup:

```
(setq smex-save-file "~/.emacs.d/settings/smex-items")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'smex)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-X") 'smex-major-mode-commands)

(eval-after-load 'smex
  `(defun smex-prepare-ido-bindings ()
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "TAB") 'minibuffer-complete)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-,") 'smex-describe-function)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-w") 'smex-where-is)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-.") 'smex-find-function)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-a") 'move-beginning-of-line)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-p") 'previous-history-element)
     ;;
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-e") 'end-of-visual-line)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-r") 'end-of-visual-line)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-s") 'end-of-visual-line)
     ))
```

Comment: I tried `emacs -Q` then loaded `smex.el`. Here is no call to `isearch`, when pressing `C-s` as you described.  Also, `C-h k C-s` during smex says: `C-s runs the command ido-next-match (found in ido-completion-map),`. I would say there is something else in your config interfering.

Comment: This issue started to emerge after I added following configuration into my init.el file https://github.com/rksm/emacs-rust-config, if you try it using `emacs -q --load "/path/to/standalone.el"` I believe you may face with `C-s` causing to open `i-search`

Comment: I did not run your config, I just took a look. Why do you think it is a `ido` or `smex` issue, when you enable `selectrum`?  `selectrum` is some alternative for `ido`. Your standalone.el is small enough, you could just bisect to find the error.

Comment: Hm I deleted `selectrum` but still having the same issue :-( I will try to bisect `standlone.el` file if I can find something I will update the question. Could it be related to enabling `lsp` ?

Comment: I am having same error when I am opening a file using `emacs -q -nw file.py`

Comment: If searching a word with ```C-s```, and then you need to search again the same word, usually press ```C-s``` twice, to avoid typing the same word again. If no previous search, it is normal to get the error message observed.

Comment: Why do you need three key chords for the same function ```end-of-visual-line```? Take care there are some other keys already used (```C-p```) - so in this case it is normal to disable previous binding before using for a new function.

Comment: I have tried `nil` but it didn't work, I was just testing to make ways to make `C-s` and `C-r` disable